# Error plots in MMA 12.0

Tags: plotting, core-language

Suppose I have the following data and associated quartiles:

```
data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {40, 10}];
qs = Quartiles[data]
```

I want to make an ErrorListPlot from the quartiles.  One approach is

```
toplot = Around[#[[2]], Differences@#] & /@ qs
ListLinePlot[toplot, IntervalMarkers -> "Fences"]
```

Is this the currently intended approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that making error plots easier was a major consideration behind the move to introduce `Around`, so I would say that this is the intended way of constructing an error plot now.

I think it addresses two key areas (in terms of plot construction):

1. Being able to easily add x error, y errors, or both.
2. Being able to use error bars on Linear-Log, Log-Linear, and Log-Log graphs which was a pain before.

$ $

```
x = Around[#, RandomReal[{-0.5, 0.5}, 2]] & /@ Range[20];
y = Around[#, RandomReal[{-0.5, 0.5}, 2]] & /@ Range[20];
ListPlot[
 {x, y}\[Transpose],
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}
]
```

[image: Log-log plot with error bars.]